# Flex Get the tab Index

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I want to get tab Index with it's id. My tabs are in a tabNavigator.

```
this.tabid.instanceIndex returns -1

this.tabid.tabIndex returns -1
```

Do I have enable order or any property in tab Navigator to get the index of a tab?

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but I can tell you that the 'tabIndex' property is related to the FocusManager (because you shift the focus with the Tab key) and has nothing to do with TabNavigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the index of a child of the TabNavigator, you can use

```
myNavigator.getChildIndex(myCanvas2);
```

This *should* map to its tab index.